# How can I hide dock in application menu from GNOME Shell?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

After I installed `plank` as my dock panel, I removed the default Ubuntu dock by running

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Then Ubuntu dock is not on my desktop anymore, but when I open the application menu or Activities overview it is there, how can I hide it?

Removed dock shows on the left:
[image: Removed dock shows on the left]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[**Hide Dash X**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/805/hide-dash/)" to achieve your goal.

[image]

**Other alternative extensions:**

1. [**Remove Dash**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1297/remove-dash/)
2. [**No Dash in Overview**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2654/no-dash-in-overview/)

Simply removing `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` would not get rid of the [GNOME dash](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design#Dash). The dash is a default feature of GNOME shell. It only in appears *Activities* overview or *Applications* overview ("*Show Applications*" screen).
The `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` package is an Ubuntu-only modification (a fork of the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension), which converts the dash into a customisable dock. The dock appears anywhere, *not* just in Activities or Applications overview, and also has some other extra features.
So removing the package would only remove the dock-like feature, but the dash will stay as it is since it's an inbuilt feature of GNOME shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension [Overview Dash Hide](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5013/overview-dash-hide/) to hide the dock

Demo :

-> [Before enabling extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDzhs.png)

-> [After enabling extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrqTO.png)

Comment: I don't see any difference between the images..