# Double dock on Activities overview and dock shown when screen is locked

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

I got a small problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and GNOME and that is when I open show applications I get a duplicate dock. How do I remove that one?

[image: extra small launcher]

Also second issue is that the dock is still shown when screen is locked. Does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: Have you installed the "Dash to Dock" extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu 17.10 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-17-10-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

For someone still looking for a fix, in Ubuntu 18.04 I installed Dash to Dock and after some time it started showing two docks in the Applications menu. I went on the dash to dock settings and *toggled on and off* the **"Show on all monitors" switch** and the second dash was gone. I hope it doesn't return.

Comment: Yep, that also worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave this here in case anyone else needed it. On my Ubuntu 20.04 toggling the "Show on all monotors" doesn't help. What we are seeing is two different docks. One simple thing to do is the remove the one that shows up in the applications menu.

The answer to that can be found here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1036623/710516

Short answer:
Install [Hide Dash X](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/805/hide-dash/) and hide the other dash.