# Dash to Dock doesn't disable even uninstalled

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I installed the "Dash to Dock" extension. It worked, but I didn't like it, so I removed it.
But the dock is same as before, and I checked if the "Ubuntu Dock" is on, but isn't.

My dock is like this:
[image: Dash to Dock "enabled"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update* In older Ubuntu version, this answer would only have been applicable to a Gnome session (`vanilla-gnome-desktop` or `gnome-session`). In newer Ubuntu versions, the "Ubuntu Dock" can conveniently be disabled using `gnome-shell-extension-prefs.

Ubuntu Dock appears to be hardly tied into the Ubuntu session. You can only disable it by directly disabling system files. If you do not want to use Ubuntu Dock, the preferred approach is to install `gnome-session`. During login, select the "Gnome on xorg" session. You will then have a plain Gnome Shell without dock, without extra Gnome applications, but however retaining all theming of Ubuntu.

Then head to Gnome Tweaks and enable "Desktop icons". If you wish, you can reactivate/disable Ubuntu Dock there. The only difference will be that your clock will remain in the center of the entire screen, while in the Ubuntu session, the clock is centered in the horizontal area not occupied by the dock.

*Original answer*
Ubuntu Dock is a fork of Dash to Dock, and uses the same configuration settings. Thus, if you installed Dash to Dock, settings remain after you remove it.

As a quirk, Ubuntu Dock may remain visible, even though it is disabled in "Gnome Tweaks". Just head to "Gnome Tweaks", "Extensions" tab, enable Ubuntu Dock briefly, then disable it again. Now, Ubuntu Dock will effectively be disabled, and the Gnome Tweak Extensions tab will be "in sync" with its actual status.

If you wish to use Ubuntu Dock extension, then turn it back on in Gnome Tweaks.

If you wish to restore the default configuration, then run the command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/
```

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu Dock can be simply disabled like that from the Tweaks app? In my experience, *in a default Ubuntu session*, the toggle state of Ubuntu Dock (and Ubuntu Appindicators) extension never really matters. I have also seen many people *complaining* the same in various sites and forums.

Comment: I will check in an Ubuntu session. I am using a Gnome session.

Comment: Sure this helped you? It might indeed work on your long term support version 18.04, but I noticed that now in the interim release 19.10, one cannot disable the extension using Tweaks in the standard Ubuntu session, as @pomsky pointed out. If you confirm, I will add that this will not anymore work on later Ubuntu versions.

Comment: It's not about difference between releases, from my experience (corroborated by others) it does *not* work in a default Ubuntu session with *any* Ubuntu release starting from 17.10. Not sure why OP accepted it, most probably they mistakenly though this is the one which finally solves the issue. But in reality they already (before you posted your answer) [tried some solution(s) linked in my answer and that *did do the job*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195921/dash-to-dock-doesnt-disable-even-uninstalled/1195925#comment2003375_1195925).

Comment: Since you cannot delete this answer now, perhaps edit in a caveat that this is supposed to work in a 'GNOME session'? Also how one should get the GNOME session.

Answer (score 1):

> checked if the "Ubuntu Dock" is **on**, but isn't

Ubuntu Dock is a pre-installed system extension for GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 17.10 and later releases. It *cannot* be reliably disabled in the default Ubuntu session using tools like GNOME Tweaks or others. Refer to this to remove the dock: [How can I get rid of the dock in Ubuntu 18?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138/480481)

Comment: It... worked? Now my dock is only on activities menu (I'm already tried this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391588#post_13765563 but i got the same error of before)

Comment: @KaigoGames That's expected. That's *not* actually the dock, it is the [GNOME **dash**](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities). The dash is a default feature of GNOME Shell, it is *supposed to* appear in Activities (and applications) overview. Dash to Dock, as its name suggests, converts the dash to a fully-fledged dock (and Ubuntu Dock is a fork of Dash to Dock). However, you can remove the dash too [using some extensions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036623/480481).